Using ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro when Excel is only running for Comm automation
I'm trying to create a unit test for a function that runs in a background worker from Excel. My unit test can start the background worker fine but when the BW completes we use ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro from ExcelDNA to process the result. This works in the normal user flow fine
private void BW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{ // This is the worker thread-completed code
    ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro(() =>
    {
        string[] outputs = (string[])e.Result;
        if (outputs.Length < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve result", title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            Common.ExitToExcel();
            return;
        }

However if I run this from my unit test without the Excel window visible I get the following error:
ExcelDna.Integration.dll!ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro(ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelAction action)  Unknown

Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in
ExcelDna.Integration.dll An unhandled exception of type
'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ExcelDna.Integration.dll
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Excel is being opened via the Excel Interop when this error occurs in test mode
xl.Application excelApp = new xl.Application(); //open an Excel application with the given workbook
xl.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath);

Is there something I need to do here to initialise the ExcelDNA Integration correctly when Excel is started via the Interop and running without a visible GUI?

To be clear, does it work as you expect when you add Application.Visible = true after opening Excel?

Hi @Govert, no this doesn't change the behaviour. I get the same error with the Excel Window visible if it was started via the C# Interop

We created a helper library called ExcelDna.Testing https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Tutorials/tree/master/Testing to help with unit testing. Maybe you can give that a try. Otherwise, I suggest making a small example I can test, and posting to the Excel-DNA Google group https://groups.google.com/g/exceldna where it's a bit easier to discuss.
